# spark.driver.extraClassPath doesn't work in virtual PySpark environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm saving data to a Postgres database and the job failed with the following:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o186.jdbc. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Until I downloaded the postgres jar to the `spark/jars` folder when I had spark installed globally.

I have sense moved to a new machine and instead only installed pyspark in a virtual environemnt (venv) via pip.

I tried setting the extraClassPath config value to my jar folder inside the virtual directory but that didn't work:

```
session = SparkSession \
         .builder \
         .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/me/source/acme/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/postgresql-42.2.6.jar") \
         .getOrCreate()
```

Have tried relative and absolute path as well as wild card (*) and full filename.  Nothing seems to work.

Setting the `spark.jars.packages` did correctly load the package from Maven however:

```
     .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.6') \
```

How can I make the extraClassPath work?

Answer (score -1):

You will also need to add jar in executor class path.

```
session = SparkSession \
         .builder \
         .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/me/source/acme/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/postgresql-42.2.6.jar") \
         .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/me/source/acme/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/postgresql-42.2.6.jar") \
         .getOrCreate()
```

EDIT:
To semantically replicate `spark.jars.package` you can use `spark.jars` with absolute path to jar file. Also just to be sure check your jar and confirm it has proper MENIFEST for driver.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.  I read the executor path is redundant in later versions of spark and driver covers both.

Comment: Could you specify version of spark in that case? It seems to be missing from the question. Also what master and mode of submission you use.

Comment: Python 3.6.8 and Spark 2.4.3.  I'm just running locally with the default PySpark PIP install on a virtual environement (venv).